# regex pipe delimiter with groups

Tags: python, regex

I have a url within a URL that's not encoded. It looks like this

```
https://myhost.mydomain.com/pnLVyL7HjrxMlxjBQkhcOMr2WUs=/400x400/https://myhost.mydomain.com/images/98f9a734-52e2-4616-adf7-bf0165bbf738.png
```

My domain can be `mydomain.com` or `mydomain.io` . Also
The `/400x400/` part can actually vary and be like `/blahblah/XxY/blahblah` or it can be totally missing. The image can be `jpg, jpeg, png`

I want to extract the second part of the URL at the end

```
https://myhost.mydomain.com/images/98f9a734-52e2-4616-adf7-bf0165bbf738.png
```

I have regex like this

```
https://myhost.mydomain.com/[a-zA-Z0-9=]*/.+[\/a-zA-Z0-9]?(/https://[a-zA-Z0-9=-]*.mydomain.(com|io)/images/[a-zA-Z0-9-]*.(png|jpg|jpeg))
```

This identifies it as 4 groups
[image]

However, I want to extract the second URL as a group - so the whole `https://myhost.mydomain.com/images/98f9a734-52e2-4616-adf7-bf0165bbf738.png`

Can you please help me fix my regex? Thanks !

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't your desired match already in group 1? What exactly seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest this approach:

```
https?(?!.*https?):\/\/.*\bmydomain\.(?:com|io).*
```

This regex uses a negative lookahead to ensure that the URL we match is the last one in the input string.  Sample script:

```
inp = "https://myhost.mydomain.com/pnLVyL7HjrxMlxjBQkhcOMr2WUs=/400x400/https://myhost.mydomain.com/images/98f9a734-52e2-4616-adf7-bf0165bbf738.png"
url = re.findall(r'https?(?!.*https?):\/\/.*\bmydomain\.(?:com|io).*', inp)[0]
print(url)
```

This prints:

```
https://myhost.mydomain.com/images/98f9a734-52e2-4616-adf7-bf0165bbf738.png
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
import re

s = "https://myhost.mydomain.com/pnLVyL7HjrxMlxjBQkhcOMr2WUs=/400x400/https://myhost.mydomain.com/images/98f9a734-52e2-4616-adf7-bf0165bbf738.png"

m = re.search(r"https://.+(https.+)$", s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
https://myhost.mydomain.com/images/98f9a734-52e2-4616-adf7-bf0165bbf738.png
```

Answer (score 1):

As there are 2 links, you could match the first link and capture the second link in group 1.

```
https?://myhost\.mydomain\.(?:com|io)/\S*?(https?://myhost\.mydomain\.(?:com|io)/\S*\.(?:jpe?g|png))
```

- `https?://myhost\.mydomain\.(?:com|io)/` Match the start of the first link
- `\S*?` Match 0+ times a non whitespace char non greedy
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `https?://myhost\.mydomain\.(?:com|io)/` Match the start of the second link
  - `\S*` Match 0+ times a non whitespace char
  - `\.(?:jpe?g|png)` Match either .jpg or .jpeg or .png
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FhkKq1/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/qoHLgV)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"https?://myhost\.mydomain\.(?:com|io)/\S*?(https?://myhost\.mydomain\.(?:com|io)/\S*\.(?:jpe?g|png))"
test_str = ("https://myhost.mydomain.com/pnLVyL7HjrxMlxjBQkhcOMr2WUs=/400x400/https://myhost.mydomain.com/images/98f9a734-52e2-4616-adf7-bf0165bbf738.png")

matches = re.search(regex, test_str)

if matches:
    print(matches.group(1))
```

Output

```
https://myhost.mydomain.com/images/98f9a734-52e2-4616-adf7-bf0165bbf738.png
```